# List Last Windows Password Change For All Users On A Non-Domain System

Tags: windows, powershell, system-administration

I have found an answer to this question for systems that are attached to an AD domain controller.  However, this question is for standalone systems where there is no possibility of attaching to a domain controller.  Essentially, air-gapped systems.

Short and sweet:  Is there a way to list the last time each user changed their Windows password for a non-domain, air-gapped system (either Windows 7 or 10) all at once either as a batch file or PowerShell script?

I know that net user {username} | find /I "Password last set" will do it for them one at a time.  However, that would be tedious to run multiple times per machine and we have over 60 systems of this type.  So I'm looking for a way to do this in one fell swoop, if possible.

As a caveat, we don't have the option of installing the activedirectory module in PowerShell for this.  Also, since the majority of the systems are Windows 7, we don't have access to the Bash command line tools that would be available in Windows 10.

Any and all help with regard to this is appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't `NET USER` list the local accounts? Can you write a batch script that calls `NET USER` to get the accounts, then loop through that list and call `NET USER {username} | find /I "Password last set"`?

Comment: Yes, NET USER does list all of the local accounts. However, NET USER returns its output in a format that I am unsure how to process due to the way the fields are set up.  Otherwise, yes, a simple run of NET USER and piping it to a text file and reading it through a looping mechanism would be an easy choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way using the ADSI WinNT provider:

```
$computerName = [Net.Dns]::GetHostName()  # i.e., local computer
$computer = [ADSI] "WinNT://$computerName,Computer"
$childObjects = $computer.Children
foreach ( $childObject in $childObjects ) {
  if ( $childObject.Class -eq "User" ) {
    if ( $childObject.PasswordAge[0] -gt 0 ) {
      $pwdLastSet = (Get-Date).AddSeconds(-$childObject.PasswordAge[0])
    }
    else {
      $pwdLastSet = $null
    }
    $childObject | Select-Object `
      @{Name="AdsPath";         Expression={$_.AdsPath}},
      @{Name="PasswordLastSet"; Expression={$pwdLastSet}}
  }
}
```

Comment: For some reason this hangs when we attempt to run it.  We get no output and have to do a hard break to exit.  Not exactly sure why though, but we also can't invoke the debugger.  The only thing that comes up is the full path to the script running, but zero output.  Weird.

Comment: I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Are you running it in the Powershell ISE?

Comment: Yes.  Running it in Powershell ISE.  Tried multiple systems and get the same result on all of them.  Will give it a try on a system at home to verify as well later tonight.

Comment: Try changing `"."` to `[Net.Dns]::GetHostName()` for the `$computerName` variable assignment (this is now in the answer).

Comment: That works perfectly and doesn't hang.  Output is immediate and exactly what we were looking for.

Comment: Sounds good. I am curious why `"."` rather than the computer name causes it to hang, but in any case the workaround is simple.